# Dyndns updater with http get

Tags: c#, http, dyndns

I need to update our dyndns zones with an application.

Their api documentation is located [here](https://help.dyn.com/remote-access-api/perform-update/)

They say i need to make a get request like so:

```
GET /nic/update?    hostname=yourhostname&myip=ipaddress&wildcard=NOCHG&mx=NOCHG&backmx=NOCHG HTTP/1.0
Host: members.dyndns.org
Authorization: Basic base-64-authorization
User-Agent: Company - Device - Version Number
```

How would I do this in c# ?

I have tried this:

```
String request = "/nic/update?hostname=yourhostname&myip=ipaddress&wildcard=NOCHG&mx=NOCHG&backmx=NOCHG HTTP/1.0";
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(request);
WebResponse webResp = webRequest.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(webResp.ToString()
```

But how do I do the hostname and all that?

Comment: What do you mean by, 'how do I do the hostname' ?

Comment: In the example they have host members.dynds.org   . in my request string i dont have that?

Comment: No but you have some other hostname that points to your IP

Comment: Yes but that is a parameters which they reqire. the hostname of the server to send the request to is still needed.

Comment: I'm not sure what is confusing you have to send a HTTP GET to members.dyndns.org with the path /nic/update?hostname=yourhostname&myip=ipaddress&wildcard=NOCHG&mx=NOCHG&backmx=NOCHG where hostname is your username/hostnames you want to update

Comment: Yes. But I am not doing that in my code. How do I do that?

Comment: You have to add it to the url: `var request = "http://members.dyndns.org/nic/update?hostname=yourhostname&myip=ipaddress&wildcard=NOCHG&mx=NOCHG&backmx=NOCHG";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wanted to post my code which I eventually got right, Incase other may need help with it one day!

I have broken it up into some sub functions for simplicity. Don't let it scare you.

```
/// <summary>
/// Call this from another class to update a zone.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="host">The full name of the host</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public string Update(String host)
{
    string url = BuildUrl(host, Ip);
    return PerformUpdate(url);
}
```

Here is A function to build the url

```
 /// <summary>
 /// //Constructs the url to send the get request to.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="hostname">the hostname </param>
 /// <param name="ip">the ipaddress</param>
 /// <returns>The complete String</returns>
 private string BuildUrl(String hostname, String ip)
 {
    return BaseUrl + "hostname=" + hostname + "&myip=" + ip;
 }
```

Here is the function that does the update:

```
/// <summary>
/// Performs the actual request to the dyndns server to update the entity
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url">url to post</param>
private String PerformUpdate(String url)
{
   HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
   NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
   request.UserAgent = Username + " - " + Password + " - " + "0.01";
   request.Credentials = creds;
   request.Method = "GET";
   HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
   Stream reply = response.GetResponseStream();
   StreamReader readReply = new StreamReader(reply);
   return readReply.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: with `MyWebRequest content    = new MyWebRequest("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");` you could also get your IP. of course you have to cut the content to the ip

Answer (score 0):

```
// External/Public IP
string externalIP = string.Empty;
externalIP = GetUserIPAddress();
externalIP = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
externalIP = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"))
            .Matches(externalIP)[0].ToString();
```

Hope this will resolve your problem. :)